# Where can I buy the game "Infinity Blade" without using IOS?

Tags: infinity-blade

I want to play Infinity Blade, but I can't find the game for anything but IOS, which I don't have. Is there a way I can play it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Unfortunately, this is game exclusive to iOS. The only option would be if someone wrote an iOS emulator/simulator, but I've never heard of one.